# What is the proper use case for readfilesync with node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this code below where I can now read the raw sql files put them into the var of selectFrom by using readFileSync for a server side CLI type of exercise. The question I have, is it okay not to have a call back on server side coding or should it always be done the callback way not to block the IO. I know this is just a learning exercise but I want it to be right to grow my knowledge and pick up good habits.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var sqlFile = 'inventory.sql'
var sqlPath = './SQLs/'

var selectFrom = fs.readFileSync(sqlPath + sqlFile, 'utf8')

console.log(selectFrom)
```

Comment: since it runs once and considering that everything in say, php, is sync, it's not unforgivable. It's when you have something that lots of users will be hitting, that the async pattern will give you more bang for your server buck in terms of latency and capacity. in this example, there's no need or benefit of using the more complicated callback approach.

Comment: That is a good rule of thumb, "when I have something that lots of users will be hitting" make it Async.

Comment: yeah, if it's just some utility you run yourself performance (especially in micro amounts) is not as important as simplicity or future readability, imho. in prod, only use sync to init the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Sync function only while server loading. After it started use async mode. Even if for you this job can be done in sync mode, there still can be some parallel user contacting your server. While Sync functions WHOLE SERVER stop to response.